# How to update a record with drupal_write_record?

Tags: nodes

I do not understand how to update a record with drupal_write_record.

I want to update column "vid," in table "node," with the value `$value`, where "nid" equals `$key`.

This is what I have, and it doesn't look right, nor does it work. I can't find any examples.

```
$table = 'node';
$record = new stdClass();
$record->vid = $value;
drupal_write_record($table, $record, array('nid' => $key));
```

To be clear: I want to insert `$value` into column "vid" where the value `$key` exists in column "nid"; this is all happening in table node.

Comment: drupal_write_record($table, $record, 'nid'); // $record->nid should contain NID value.

Comment: THANKS kalabro. You are correct. This does an update. I would never have guessed that in a million years.

Answer (score 7):

`drupal_write_record` updates an entire record, not a single column. With `drupal_write_record` you could do this.

```
$node = node_load($nid);
$node->vid = $vid;
drupal_write_record('node', $node, 'nid');
```

But dealing with nodes, you can use `node_save` instead, which also handles saving fields and other data. Using `node_save` is recommended way of saving alterations to a node, since it also deals with revisions issues along with fields, hook notification ect. It's simple to use:

```
$node = node_load($nid);
$node->vid = $vid;
node_save($node);
```

If you want to update a single value in a datebase, you can use SQL (`db_query`) or the `db_update` function which is two ways of running SQL on your database. The `db_update` utilizes the Drupal query builder, and will work on any database backend the Drupal supports (now and in the furture):

```
db_query("UPDATE {node} SET vid = :vid WHERE nid = :nid;",
  array(':nid' => $nid, ':vid' => $vid)
);

$num_updated = db_update('node')
  ->fields(array(
    'vid' => $vid,
  ))
  ->condition('nid $nid)
  ->execute();
```

`drupal_write_record` will itself use `db_update`, a snippet of the code looks like this:

```
$query = db_update($table)->fields($fields);
  foreach ($primary_keys as $key) {
    $query->condition($key, $object->$key);
  }
```

Which basicly creates an update query, updating all of the fields, and using all of the values set in primary key as the condition.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. What do you make of the documentation on #primary_keys on this page then? http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_write_record/7

Comment: I meant $primary_keys.

Comment: @user1919784 $primary_keys is either a string or array of the column names that is going to be used to update the specific record. Typically it is the primary keys of the database table you want to use.

Comment: `node_save()` is a better function to use when saving a node.

Comment: @kiamlaluno I agree, I would go so far as to saying it's the recommended way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

According to [drupal_write_record](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_write_record/7) the operation was an `UPDATE` or an `INSERT` you need to know whether the record existed or not before committing the transaction. This is not what drupal_write_record() does. This function just checks it's arguments and issues an update or an insert accordingly. So there is **really no way** to tell if the function did an `INSERT` or an `UPDATE`.

The solution is using [db_merge()](http://drupal.org/node/310085) query, it is a relatively new SQL ANSI standard that does exactly what I needed (and in the case of MySQL does it in an atomic transaction).

```
$return_value = db_merge('mytable')
            ->key(array('id' => $key))
            ->fields($fields)
            ->updateFields(array(
                'updatedon' => $now,
            ))
            ->execute();
```

The return value is an integer returning 1 for inserts and 2 for updates.